# Help me understand Gröbner basis result please

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, mathematica, groebner-basis

I'm practicing a bit with Gröbner bases but I'm not understanding the following result I obtain from Mathematica:

```
GroebnerBasis[{
    (2 a[1] - a[2] - a[3]) (a[2] - a[3])^4, 
    (a[2] - a[3])^2 (5 a[1]^2 - 5 a[1] a[2] + 2 a[2]^2 - 5 a[1] a[3] + a[2] a[3] + 
 2 a[3]^2)
}, 
{x}]
```

So here I'm computing the  Gröbner basis of the terms

```
(2 a[1] - a[2] - a[3]) (a[2] - a[3])^4
```

and

```
 (a[2] - a[3])^2 (5 a[1]^2 - 5 a[1] a[2] + 2 a[2]^2 - 5 a[1] a[3] + a[2] a[3] + 
 2 a[3]^2)
```

And I indicate that my only variable $x$. This is the result Mathematica returns:

```
{(a[2] - a[3])^6, 
(2 a[1] - a[2] - a[3]) (a[2] - a[3])^4, 
(a[2] - a[3])^2 (5 a[1]^2 - 5 a[1] a[2] + 2 a[2]^2 - 5 a[1] a[3] + 
a[2] a[3] + 2 a[3]^2)}
```

So the term

```
(a[2] - a[3])^6
```

Has been added. But I don't understand this. I expected the basis of $2$ constants (since neither expression involves $x$ they are just constants) to just be the same again. I also don't understand how this result follows from the algorithm for computing a Gröbner basis, since the leading term of both expressions is just the whole expression, so when calculating their S-polynomials, wouldn't it just be $0$?

Any explanation of why this is the result would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica doesn't just applies the Buchberger algorithm and returns a Groebner basis. It returns a reduced Groebner basis. So, if your polynomial set contains any non-zero constant, the result is {1}. 
For example GroebnerBasis[{ 1/y, z}, {x}] returns {1}.
However, if your set consists of constants that can be eventually zero, Mathematica returns a reduced Groebner basis of the constants (parameter variables) that can be zero. Hence GroebnerBasis[{ y, z}, {x}] gives {z, y};
 but GroebnerBasis[{ t/y, z}, {x}] gives {z, t}. Similarly
GroebnerBasis[{(y - z) y, (y - z) z}, {x}] gives {y z - z^2, y^2 - z^2}.

If an expression of constants is nonzero, I don't really understand what Mathematica computes, for example GroebnerBasis[{(y - z) y, y/(y - z) }, {x}] returns {y, y/(y - z)} which is not any Groebner basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I expected it to be something like this. I would just like to understand what happens in that last example of yours as wel.

Comment: Apparently the algorithm of Mathematica is unable to deal with such cases. If you put GroebnerBasis[{t/(y - z), (y - z) t}, {x}] then it returns {0,t}, which makes no sense at all, because the reduced Groebnerbasis of {0,t} is {t}.

Comment: I've though about this, but I'm not really understanding exactly what is going on here. The way I see it is that Mathematica returns a set of expressions that basically 'indicate' whether $1$ is in the ideal, or all constants are $0$. Can you indicate exactly what Mathematica does to the input to arrive at those outputs? Does it just invoke Solve[constant==0,x] and then add that result to the basis or something? And I'm also not seeing how these results are explained by the fact that a reduced basis is returned. Basically, I would really appreciate some more details here.

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm of Mathematica. The last example seems to be a bug for me, so you can write to Wolfram, they should be able to fix the bug and explain the algorithm. I just played around with some examples with constant polynomials and found the examples and put them in my answer. I only use the fact that Mathematica returns a reduced Groebner basis, i.e., no term of the polynomials is divided by the leading term of any other, and the leading coefficients are brought to 1.

Comment: So, if a non-zero constant is present, it divides any other term of the basis, so everything is eliminated but the non-zero constant, and this constant is brought to 1. Your original question was an explanation of the appearance of the term $(a_2-a_3)^6$, which comes from the fact that the algorithm computes the Groebner basis of possibly zero parameter variables.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I'm wondering how it find this specific term $(a_2-a_3)^6$ in this specific scenario; what exactly does it compute and what operations are performed on which terms that lead to $(a_2-a_3)^6$ being added?

Comment: You have to apply the Buchberger algorithm to the two polynomials (in a[1],a[2] and a[3], in that order), and then reduce the resulting basis. I suggest to practice with smaller polynomials, since the computations are quite lengthy.